# How to convert a list of cell references to cells in other worksheets into hyperlinks

Tags: excel, vba

I have a summary worksheet that contains references to other worksheets within the same workbook.  The references are simple formulae (i.e. =Sheet2!D23).  I'd like to convert these to hyperlinks.  I'd like the hyperlinks to display the value of the referenced cells.

I can do this individually but the spreadsheet is large and there are hundreds of these references.

Can someone suggest an easier way to batch convert these references to hyperlinks?

Comment: Kindly check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606785/how-do-i-pass-the-contents-of-the-target-range-in-a-worksheet-selectionchange?noredirect=1#comment22156661_15606785

Answer (score 1):

Select a range of cells that includes the ones you want to link, then run this macro.
 It will only link values that reside on a different sheet, it will not link to cells on the current sheet. If you want to link all cells even if the value comes from the same sheet just remove the `If..End If` wrapper around `rng.Hyperlinks.Add rng, "", Replace(rng.Formula, "=", "")`.

```
Sub makeLinks()
    Dim rng As Range
    For Each rng In Selection
        If rng.Formula Like "=*!*" Then
            rng.Hyperlinks.Add rng, "", Replace(rng.Formula, "=", "")
        End If
    Next rng
End Sub
```